# NodeJS express getting hanging requests on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, express, windows-10

I have been getting hanging requests, with only expressjs, on my windows 10 machine. The code I will post is the current version of the code; it was tried a) without async, and b) without redis anywhere and just the 'test' route. The request just hangs, whether called from Postman or accessed directly from a browser. Admin privileges were given with the same result.

```js
    const express = require('express')
    import { createClient } from "redis"
    import { UserApi } from "./api/users"
    
    (async () => {
        const app = express()
        const client = createClient()
    
        //Check redis
        client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err))
    
        //Connect to redis client
        await client.connect()
    
        //Create API instances
        const ua = new UserApi(client)
    
        //Initialize middleware\
        app.use(express.json)
    
        //Create routes
        //test
        app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
            res.send("got")
        })
    
        //signup - creates user
        app.post("/signup", async function(req, res) {
            console.log("starting")
            const u = {username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}
    
            console.log("why")
            try {
                console.log("trying")
                const token = await ua.create(u)
                res.send(token)
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).send(error)
            }
        })
    
    
        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log("server up")
        })
    }) ()
```

Comment: just move /test route above redis connect or remove the redis code see if it can reach /test

Comment: Tried - same problem.

Comment: `app.use(express.json()) ; ` ,please rectify this first

Comment: Wow that worked! Can't believe i forgot that....